# Dúvida: como inserir múltiplas linhas usando $_GET e MySqli do mesmo arquivo.php para a mesma tabela

Tags: php, mysqli

Fala gelera! Preciso de um help.

Estou criando algumas telas com PHP 7.4 + MySqli + Apache, rodando em um Ubuntu 18.04.

Tenho um arquivo/script `registro_serra.php`, nele eu capturo variáveis para inserir na tabela `corte_torete` com o método `$_GET` de um Formulário. Da seguinte forma:

```
<form action="registro_serra.php" method="GET">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Comprimento do Torete 1</label>
    <select class="form-control text-center" id="comprimento_torete" name="comprimento_torete"> 
      <option value="11">11 Centímetros</option> 
      <option value="">...</option> 
      <option value="20">20 Centímetros</option>
    </select>
```

Estou conseguindo capturar essas variáveis e inserir no B.D. Da seguinte forma:

```
if(isset($_GET['btn-gravar-torete1'])):
// Gravando na tabela
$gravatt = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO corte_torete (nro_lote...volume_torete) VALUES ('$lote3'...'$volume_tt')");
mysqli_close($connect);
```

Neste mesmo arquivo, eu preciso capturar os mesmo valores para inserir na mesma tabela. Em outro conjunto identificado como name 'torete2'.

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Comprimento do Torete 2</label>
    <select class="form-control text-center" id="comprimento_torete_2" name="comprimento_torete_2"> 
      <option value="11">11 Centímetros</option> 
      <option value="">...</option> 
      <option value="20">20 Centímetros</option>
    </select>
```

Envio pro B.D do mesmo jeito

```
if(isset($_GET['btn-gravar-torete_2'])):
// Gravando na tabela
$gravatt_2 = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO corte_torete (nro_lote...volume_torete) VALUES ('$lote3_2'...'$volume_tt_2')");
mysqli_close($connect);
```

Ambos inserem bonitinho, mas só 1 por vez, preciso inserir até 9 vezes assim, na mesma página, pra mesma tabela. 
Se eu apago o registro pelo PHPmyAdmin, permite uma nova inserção... Tentei com $_POST, dá na mesma. Alguma sugestão?

Habilitei para mostrar os erros, e quando não grava, retorna **Error: Query was empty**

Agradeço! É meu primeiro post aqui :)

Answer (score 0):

Vamos realizar uma pequena alteração em seu `HTML` para ser melhor de controlar quantos registro existem para realizar a inserção dos dados na tabela.

- No `name` do select do Comprimento do Torete será de melhor uso, a implementação de vetor para armazenar seus dados, ficando todos os `names` como `name="comprimento_torete[]"`.

Com o parâmetro sendo passado como um vetor ou array como queira chamar, fica ainda mais para recuperar os dados.

---

- **Formulário**

  ```
  <form action="registro_serra.php" method="GET">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Comprimento do Torete 1</label>
          <select class="form-control text-center" id="comprimento_torete" name="comprimento_torete[]"> 
              <option value="11">11 Centímetros</option> 
              <option value="...">...</option> 
              <option value="20">20 Centímetros</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Comprimento do Torete 2</label>
          <select class="form-control text-center" id="comprimento_torete2" name="comprimento_torete[]"> 
              <option value="11">11 Centímetros</option> 
              <option value="...">...</option> 
              <option value="20">20 Centímetros</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Comprimento do Torete 3</label>
          <select class="form-control text-center" id="comprimento_torete3" name="comprimento_torete[]"> 
              <option value="11">11 Centímetros</option> 
              <option value="...">...</option> 
              <option value="20">20 Centímetros</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
  ```
- **registro_serra.php**

  ```
  $c_toretes = $_GET['comprimento_torete']; // recupera array com os comprimentos
  $sql = ""; // Cria variável onde será implementado a inserção
  // Criando query se inserção 
  foreach($c_toretes as $key => $c_torete){
      $sql .= "('$c_torete')"; // valor da coluna para inserção
      $sql .= count($c_toretes) === $key + 1 ? "" : ","; // Define virgula para separar os parametros, caso seja o último item do array, não será implementado a virgula
  }
  // query se inserção
  mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO TABELA (COLUNA_COMPRIMENTO_TORETE) VALUES {$sql}");
  mysqli_close($connect);

  // Em teste realizado, a saída a query foi 
  "INSERT INTO TABELA (COLUNA_COMPRIMENTO_TORETE) VALUES ('11'),('...'),('20')"
  ```

---

### Algumas consideração

Como está sendo realizado uma query com os dados recuperado de um formulário, é muito arriscado usar o método `GET` para isso, é recomendado o método `POST`, que se torna um pouco mais seguro.

Uma segunda consideração será a validação dos dados antes de usar ele para qualquer coisa, um dos mais comuns para validação seria o [filter_var()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-var.php), como ele além de validar o dados é possível limpar os dados também, usando `SANITIZE` e `VALIDADE`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Pedro, nesse meio tempo consegui resolver! :D
Uma das alterações foi usar $_POST ao invés de $_GET
A outra foi implementar outras funções de "debug" como exemplo `code`
if ($connect->multi_query($gravatt2) === TRUE) {
    echo "Gravado.";
 } else {
    echo "Error: " . $gravatt2 . "
 " . $connect->error;
 }
`code`
Assim descobri que estava tentando inserir um valor duplicado em um campo definido como "primary" e "auto increment", removi essas propriedades, assim o B.D permitiu inserir elas duplicadas...

Comment: @JonathanWolffAndrade, que bom que conseguiu resolver sozinho, bons estudos!